# Does anyone know crawler download site tool that support log in and cookies?

Tags: java, web, web-crawler

Does someone familiar with web-crawler that support login (by form and store in cookies)?
Another option is a tool for download the site.

If you are not familiar advice for open source in java that can help with this will be more than welcome.

Thank you

Comment: You can login to a site with cURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Web-Harvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/). [Here](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/samples.php?num=4)'s an example of scraping after log in.